# Change covariance type to robust in statsmodels.logit

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to change the covariance type from non-robust to robust when doing a logistic regression using stats models in python.

I read the documentation on statsmodels.org but wasn't able to find a solution on how to do it.

If someone on here could help me that would be really awesome.

Comment: short answer: `model.fit(cov_type="hc0"`) For discrete models like Logit and for GLM all "HC" cov_types are currently just HC0.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Josef, simply specifying the `cov_type` will work:

```
model.fit(cov_type="hc0")
model.fit(cov_type="hc1")
model.fit(cov_type="hc2")
model.fit(cov_type="hc3")
```

Comment: Whats the difference between `hc0`-`hc3`? Are all of those the same in that they change the covariance type to robust, or is there a difference between 0-3?